# Pseudocode for Synchronization Problem (Card Game)

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

This is related to academics.

I'm new to synchronization based programming and am having trouble creating a pseudcode for a program that is something like this:

There's one director and N players. The
**director (an independent thread) shuffles cards (shuffle cards()), invites players
(invite players())**, and then (**distribute cards()**). the director gives
control to the first player and he suspends himself until the game has terminated. Once the director
is notified that the game ended, he checks the records (**check game()**) to verify that cards were
played according to the rules.

Each player runs as a separate thread. After a possible initialization, a player waits until she is
signalled to play a card. She then plays a card (**play card())**.
If the currently active player detects that the game has ended (**end of game()** yields true), she
notifies the director that the game is over and quits. If the game is not yet over, the player signals
the next player and suspends itself until it is her turn again.

Here's what I came up with (keeping in mind the **consumer producer** problem). Please give your feedback and suggestions:

```
void Director()
{
  shuffle_cards();
  invite_players();
  distribute_cards();
  up(&full);
  down(&empty);
  check_game();
}
```

```
void Player()
{
  down(&full);
  down(&mutex);
  play_card();
  if (end_of_game == true){
      up(&empty);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Excellent question, but I'm a bit unclear on how gameplay proceeds. Do the players go in a particular sequence, say, `0..n`, is it just a free for all or does something about the cards/gameplay impact ordering (in other words, what are the "rules" you mention)? Thanks.

Comment: We have not been given any information on the order. But I'm guessing it would make sense to consider it's from 0 to N or maybe according to the order of distribution (only if it doesn't complicate it too much).@ggorlen

Comment: in this case, I'm assuming that the check_game() function is already given. @ggorlen

Comment: Thanks. Another question: are the threads supposed to be left to work (e.g. thinking about what their move is) while they wait for their turn or do they block? I assume the first because there's no reason for multithreading if they run one after the other without overlap.

Comment: Well, we are not provided any such information regarding this. The question says "If the game is not yet over, the player signals
the next player and suspends itself until it is her turn again." Maybe for now, we can just consider the case where there's only one round first. @ggorlen

Comment: Right, I'm only thinking about one round, but during this round, are the threads blocking the entire time until they're signalled or do they do work and need to be interrupted? If they are doing work and get signalled that it's their turn, do we assume they can be left to "think" even after being notified, then play their card when they're ready?

Comment: I'm really not sure about it but logically, it sounds easier if they just end completely instead of being left to think, no? After all, in the next round, we'll use the play_card() function again anyway @ggorlen

Comment: I mean before they're signalled as other players are doing their thing, not after their turn. Think of poker players--they all think simultaneously (in programming, run on the CPU crunching numbers figuring out what card to play before they play it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Only one semaphore "full" will not do the job of waking next player.
   There will have to be N sempahores one per player for the job.
2. There has to be one semaphore for the Director.
3. I'm assuming Director in invite_players(); function creates the N threads for N players to play.

Sempahore Director = 0;

Semaphore Players[N] = {0,0, ....0};

```
void Director()
{
    while (true) {
        shuffle_cards();
        invite_players();   // create the N player threads.
        distribute_cards(); // Distribute the cards to players.
        // Set all players semaphore in lock mode.
        Players[N] = {0,0, ....0};
        // Wakeup first player to start the game.
        up(&Players[0]);
        // Wait till the game is over
        down(&Director);
        check_game();
    }
}

void Player(int i) {
    // i is the player number playing the game in this thread.
    // Pick up the distributed cards.
    pickupCards();
    // Start the game.
    while (true) {
        // Wait for your turn.
        down(&Players[i]);
        // Check for end game condition.
        if (end_of_game == true){
            // Leave the game.
            break;
        }
        // Play the game.
        play_card();
        // Wake up next player.
        up(&Players[(i+1)%N]);
    }
    // You detected the game is over.
    // Now try to pass on that information to next neighbor. 
    // If next player is still playing, she will quit and pass on the same information.
    // If next player is not playing, the end of game is broadcasted to all.
    up(&Players[(i+1)%N]);
}
```

Comment: The code above has problem. before all players exit Director can wakeup and start shuffling cards. You can stop that with having a players counter and decrement it whenever a player finds game is over. When the last player detects game is over she can wakeup the director.